# Does time series forecasting belong to supervised learning? or is it another category of machine learning?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, time-series, arima

I have been analyzing several different methods of time series forecasting such as ARIMA and SARIMA using [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) library for my final year project. Checking on past literature I have seen that regression algorithms could also be used in combination with methods such as sliding window. However what I can't clarify is what type of algorithms does time series forecasting fall in to. I'm sure it is not unsupervised, therefore does this mean that time series forecasting algorithms are supervised algorithms? or is it a different type of machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

Forecasting is a task and supervised learning describes a certain type of algorithm.

So, saying that "forecasting belong to supervised learning" is incorrect.

However, you can use supervised learning algorithms on forecasting tasks, even though this has well-known [pitfalls](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-not-to-use-machine-learning-for-time-series-forecasting-avoiding-the-pitfalls-19f9d7adf424) you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

There is alot of techniques to solve time series forecasting problems where you can use supervised or unsupervised learning ,e.g:  using unsupervised learning to cluster time series and use the cluster to forecast . 
One of the most famous techniques also , is to reframe the dataset as a supervised learning dataset so you can use some supervised algorithms , and of course it is all depending on the use case you are working on , so limiting time series algorthims to a specific type of learning is not a good idea in my opinion  .